# Вызов функции во время асинхронного парсинга python

Tags: python

Я паршу асихнронно сайт и получаю данные, но во время получения данных хочу запускать еще одну функцию, которая будет парсить по этим данным, т.е должно работать 2 процесса парсинга асинхронно.

Пример ниже

```
async def mains3(value):
    print(value)


async def mains2(items, session):
    async with session.get("https://ya.ru/") as resp:
        try:
            data = await resp.json(content_type=None)
            print(data)
            await mains3(items)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f'ERROR: {await resp.text()}')


async def mains():
    try:
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
            await asyncio.gather(*[mains2(uid, session) for uid in range(10)])

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"ERROR connector  -  {ex}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(mains())
```

Но функция main3() не выполняется... нужно чтобы она вызывалась и отрабатывала именно в тот момент, когда ее вызвали.

Comment: А у вас успешно всё выполняется или `ERROR` выходит? Если выходит `ERROR`, то просто до вызова `await mains3(items)` очередь не доходит, вот и всё.

Comment: успешно конечно

Comment: У меня при успехе всё печатает

Comment: mains3(value) вызывается во время успеха?